# Laravel 9 Call to undefined function App\Http\Middleware\web()

Tags: laravel, offline, laravel-9

Alright, so I created a middleware for my staff access only page but every time I get this error when I hop on the test site: **Call to undefined function App\Http\Middleware\web()**

Here's my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class webAPIchecker
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        $route = $request->route()->getName();

        $middleware = $request->route()->middleware();

        $post = $request->isMethod('post');

        // Offline

        $adminsOnlyPass = config('web.offlinePass');


        if ((web('offline_enabled') && !in_array(session('admins_only'), $adminsOnlyPass)) || !web('offline_enabled') && session()->has('admins_only'))
            session()->forget('admins_only');

        if (web('offline_enabled') && !session()->has('admins_only') && !Str::startsWith($route, 'offline.'))
            return redirect()->route('offline.offline');

        if (!web('offline_enabled') && Str::startsWith($route, 'offline.'))
            return $this->disabled('Offline', $middleware, $post);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the web function you use?

Comment: Maybe you forgot add your middleware to app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: I added it. I'm pretty sure the web should be connecting to the database table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:❌

```php
web('offline_enabled')
```

Use this:✅

```php
auth()->user()?->offline_enabled
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the web should be connecting to the database table.

Comment: @MohammadSaleh is `web` a database table of some sort? Have you defined the custom `web(...)` method anywhere?

Comment: @MohammadSaleh Isn't the `offline_enabled` a configuration value?

Comment: What? It's supposed to be connecting to the web database table not a config file.

Comment: @MohammadSaleh Is `offline_enabled` a column on the `users` table?

Comment: It is but in the web table in the database.

Comment: @MohammadSaleh Do you have a `User` model? Did you explicitly define a `protected $table` property on the model? Lastly, try my edited answer.

Comment: I do have a user model and the offline_enabled column is not in the users table it's in the 'web' table.

Comment: @MohammadSaleh [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72922622/edit) and show us the `web` table schema. In addition, do you have [Laravel Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze) or [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum) installed? Lastly, how do you know the logged-in user?

Comment: I don't have them installed.